# Visual studio C# chart. How to control the x-axis numbering?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, charts

I'm learning how to use charts in C# using Visual studio.

I'm writing a Windows Forms application to test the zoom and I don't like how it messes up the axis numbering.

How can I force the Y-axis grid to be placed symetrically on both sides of zero. And always include the zero if zero is between axis min and max?

And I'm only interested in the Y-axis.

[image]

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also: Please decide what you want x-axis or y-axis! - I think you need to replace the automatic labels by customlabels. Tricky..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

You can use the code below:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = n;  // Set a constant interval if you want
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = lower;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = upper;
```